# Segmented Regression to find breakpoint with on many different groups - summarize

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, segment, piecewise

I essentially have a glmm model that I am trying to break up to assess where the best breakpoint should be for the data which is compromised of many different sites over multiple years of data.  I expect there to be just one breakpoint where the population changes from declining to increasing/stable.  Attached are some made-up data:

```
df2 <-data.frame(site=c('bh',   'bh',   'bh',   'bh',   'bh',   'h1',   'h1',   'h1',   'h1',   'h1',   'h1',   'h1',   'h1',   'ha',   'ha',   'ha',   'ha',   'ha',   'ha',   'ha',   'ho',   'ho',   'ho',   'ho',   'ho',   'ho',   'ho',   'ho',   'sb',   'sb',   'sb',   'sb',   'sb',   'sb',   'sb',   'wm',   'wm',   'wm',   'wm',   'wm'), 
                 ysw=c(0,   2,  3,  5,  12, 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  13, 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  8,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  13, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  13, 1,  2,  3,  5,  12), 
                 lam=c(-1.94246067889122,   0.674238379117774,  0.123986076653627,  1.42751957163926,   -1.30153581808348,  -0.424812155072339, -0.775553269663735, 0.845160077651946,  -0.366964611913739, -0.175440305426086, -0.300162274132754, 0.602168551378997,  0.35237549500052,   0.0568625203766551, 0.0310733148322787, -0.300162274132754, -0.0866196954685079,    -0.213169737066003, -0.0409152237837699,    0.0417873189717518, -0.111072044919427, -0.9810987245661,   0.301247088636211,  0.243286146083446,  0.155205859770556,  -1.46428403001449,  1.00004342727686,   0.699056854547668,  -0.351206453188803, 0.0972573096934199, 0.431524584187451,  -0.526810501182215, -0.424812155072339, 0.602168551378997,  0.628491104967123,  0.778223626766096,  -0.300162274132754, -0.475820321699244, 0.477265995424853,  0.301247088636211
                 ))
```

I essentially want to run a segmented regression analysis for each site separately and then create a dataframe of the different estimated breakpoints so I can figure out on average what 'ysw' is when most sites recover from a decline.

I have looked at this
[Performing lm() and segmented() on multiple columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170937/performing-lm-and-segmented-on-multiple-columns-in-r) and [How to use segmented package when working with data frames with dplyr package to perform piecewise linear regression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68460350/how-to-use-segmented-package-when-working-with-data-frames-with-dplyr-package-to)

I now need a way to put the output (at least where the breakpoint should be for every site) in a dataframe. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    #Attempt 1:
out <- df2 %>% 
      nest_by(site) %>%
      mutate(my.lm = list(lm(lam ~ ysw, data = data)),
             my.seg = list(tryCatch(segmented(my.lm, seg.Z = ~ ysw),
                                    error = function(e) list(NA))))
```

Comment: You should not use `df2` inside the mutate. try `my.lm=list(lm(lam~ysw, data=data)`

Comment: Thanks onyambu. That get's me part way there. How do I create a dataframe to hold the different breakpoints for each site (in reality I have hundreds of sites but just put up a small dataset here as an example).

Comment: `df2 %>%group_by(site)%>%summarise(my_lm = list(lm(lam~ysw, cur_data())))`

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately it did not quite work.  a1<-df %>%group_by(site)%>%summarise(my.lm = list(lm(lam~ysw, cur_data()))) but I get a column with site and my.lm which just has <lm> in it instead of the breakpoint.  Not usre how to extract that from the my.seg

Comment: That is because you did not run the segmented code